# Instruction address to symbol for Java

Tags: java, binutils

Let's say I have a particular instruction address for a Java program (for whatever reason) and I want to know which function it belongs to.

If this was from a C++ program for example, I could use binutils (addr2line etc) to get this.

Is this even possible for a Java program as there's no ELF file as the bytecode is JIT-ted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[perf-map-agent](https://github.com/jrudolph/perf-map-agent) solves this problem:

> perf-map-agent is an agent that will generate such a mapping file for
>   Java applications. It consists of a Java agent written C and a small
>   Java bootstrap application which attaches the agent to a running Java
>   process.

Answer (score 2):

Have you heard about javap ??

With `javap -c MyClass.class` you can have look at bytecode instructions.

Check https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javap.html if it helps